# logout link on VF page in customer portal

Tags: visualforce, customer-portal

I want to have hyperlink on my VF page and this page has to be shown on customer portal. The hyperlink will imitate logout functionality. I used following url "/secur/logout.jsp" but it is not working. Am I missing anything here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should work:

```
"{!$Site.Prefix}/secur/logout.jsp"
```

Its what salesforce generates when you set up a force.com site.

Answer (score 2):

Use href="/secur/logout.jsp" in anchor tag

and if u want to do in ccontroller use

```
return new PageReference('/secur/logout.jsp');
```

Hope this will work for u:-)